# specific column increment in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a table Student with Column names Enroll no(auto_increment),name,class,section,roll no(auto_increment). now i need to increment the roll no column should be start from 1 irrespective of enroll no,whenever i change the class or section.

Comment: @Rahul In MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: auto_increment should take care of that (at least it does for primary keys), what's the issue you're facing? At the moment your question is way too vague to be answered.

Comment: hi rath,actually enroll no is for individual students in a school it is a primary key.however,roll no is different from enroll no,some students enrolled in a LKG class the roll no should start from no1 in LKG class,whenever one more student want to enroll in UKG class his roll no also should be start from no1 in UKG class.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use some sort of default value (1, in this case) for column **roll_no**, and change the table schema so that column **roll_no** does not use auto incrementing. Then, whenever you `INSERT` a new record, the **roll_no** field for that record will be the value 1. Column **roll_no** would hence become a calculated field when you `UPDATE` the class and section fields.

From the MySQL 5.1 manual under `CREATE` [MySQL 5.1 Manual: CREATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

```
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
      [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
      [reference_definition]
```

Notice that you can specify a DEFAULT value (see line 2 of code above) for a column.
Here is a imperfect template to get you going. Again, use the documentation if you need to.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
enroll_no int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name (blah),
class (blah),
section (blah),
roll_no NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Must be calculated before UPDATEing class or section.')
ENGIN=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET =utf8;
```

Once this system is setup, you would use `SELECT` to query the present value of a record's roll_no field before using `UPDATE` to update the class or section fields. Once you get the present value of the **roll**_no field, try adding 1 to it and using that result as the `UPDATE` value.

I'm a little rusty on my SQL and short on time, but I think it would work. Use a good reference on nested queries if you get stuck.